# What does "a[href*=#]:not([href=#])" code mean?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I don't understand clearly what does this code mean ?

```
a[href*=#]:not([href=#])
```

Thank you !

Comment: But it looks like it wants to match `href` something `=#` where "something" must not be the empty string.

Answer (score 48):

Simply:

```
a[href*=#]
```

gets all anchors (`a`) that *contain* `#` in href.

But with:

```
:not([href=#])
```

excludes anchors with href *exactly equal* to `#`.

Example:

```
<a href="#step1">yes</a>
<a href="page.php#step2">yes</a>
<a href="#">no</a>
```

the selector gets the first two anchors, but it excludes the last.

For more details you can consult the [attribute selectors chapter](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Thank you ! I have problem in Panel with Bootstrap 3 and Scolling Back to Top on this link : http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links/

Comment: that Question and Answer made my day Thanks

Comment: Problem I had was combining a smooth-scrolling script using a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"] as the selector and bootstrap Carousel using #myCarousel to target the Next/Previous buttons. I needed to exempt #myCarousel from selection just like #. The syntax for that in jquery: $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"],[href="#myCarousel"])').click...

Comment: I was looking all OVER the place for this `*=` thing.
Thanks so much!

Do you, by chance, know where something like this is documented to help me dig deeper on how something like `*=` ever became a thing?

Comment: @MarkPuchalaII https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 43):

Just in case anyone had the same problem as me with it and new version of jQuery : 
The solution is not to use `a[href*=#]:not([href=#])` but

### use

`a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])`

> This was a breaking change in jQuery 2.2.4 onwards.

Comment: ..or to escape it like: a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])

Comment: way to go my friend!

Answer (score 2):

means that all  elements with href attribute conatining `'#'`, `except` those whose href attribute  equals to `#`

Comment: really ASAT. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[That's a CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) that gets all the `a` whose `href` attribute *contains* a `#`, but are not just made up of the single `#` char.

e.g.

**Matched**

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a>
```

**Not Matched**

```
<a href="#">Top</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to start with `#`, just contain it somewhere in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is a CSS selector that matches any `a` element that has a `href` attribute containing the `#` character, but not anchor tags which have only `#`.

So for example, it'll match: `<a href="#test">Test Anchor</a>`, but not `<a href="#">Blank</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This post is ancient, but incase anyone is still looking.  Does this only grab:

```
<a href="#step1">yes</a>
<a href="page.php#step2">yes</a>
```

or will it also grab:

```
<a href="/path/to/page.php#step2">yes</a>
```

In testing, it looks like the first group only, and I need it to grab the first and the second.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34892387)